# Auto-uploading cookbooks to chef server

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, chef-infra

I recently started working with chef and am managing my cookbooks in a github repository. Every time I make a change, I am pushing my changes to the github repo then upload everything to the chef server after code promotion email approval. The job executes knife command 
for uploading to chef server.

I was wondering how you guys manage auto-upload, if at all you have to maintain multiple cookbooks. I don't know a solution as i have to maintain multiple github repos (for multiple cookbooks) along with multiple Jenkins jobs, as a commit to the repo and then execute commands to upload to the chef server  Is there an easier way to do it? Anyone already using Chef in production, how do you do it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you push your cookbook changes to the repository, the build server should be triggered to pull the changes and test your cookbook (checkout [kitchen](https://docs.chef.io/kitchen.html), [chefspec](https://docs.chef.io/chefspec.html), [inspec](https://www.chef.io/products/chef-inspec/), [foodcritic](https://docs.chef.io/foodcritic.html), [cookstyle](https://docs.chef.io/cookstyle.html)).

when the tests are passing, use use [knife](https://docs.chef.io/knife.html) or [berkshelf](https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html) to upload your cookbook to chef server

Comment: But if I have multiple cookbooks so shall I maintain multiple repositories with multiple Jenkins pipelines?

Comment: Yes, this way you will have history of builds per cookbook. Your pipelines will be very similar or even identical, so you can make use of pipeline shared libraries https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ to reduce duplication.

Comment: @sg0133: if my post answer your question, please mark as solved :)